# How to delete a row depending on values from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In my sheet called "Data" i have about 200 rows.  Column A has a ID number and the rest of the columns are just data.
In my other sheet called "Check" in column A i have list of ID numbers as well.
What i want is to delete all rows in my data sheet that has a customer ID that's in my check sheet.

So my thought process was if i do a vlookup and it returns a value then delete that row, else move to the next
for some reason this is just deleting all the rows.

```
Sub EraseDups()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, "A"), Sheet1.Range("A:A"), 1, False) > 1 Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest setting a breakpoint at the If Application.Worksheet... line then using F8 to go line by line and see what's really happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to do it....

Instead of using Vlookup or Match, use Countif, that will not produce an error so no error handling is required.

```
Sub EraseDups()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCheck As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    Set wsCheck = Sheets("Check")
    With wsData 'Change this to the specific sheet if wanted
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = N To 1 Step -1
            If Application.CountIf(wsCheck.Range("A:A"), .Cells(i, "A")) > 0 Then
               .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
         Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: tsk tsk, you copied my code, then modified it. :)  `j` is no longer needed. with your code.  And you may want to move the note to the line that sets the sheet and not the with line.  But those are just my OCD.

Comment: Yes I copied your code and tweaked it. Hope I didn't do anything wrong. :)

Comment: nope, just noticed the similarities. You did nothing wrong.  I do it all the time.

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't have any double meaning when you say that. BTW I don't think you make the mistakes all the time. :)

Comment: One thing you will learn about me, I do not hold back.  If I think that you did something wrong you will know.  I will specifically tell you that what you did was wrong.  It is not meant as criticism but as an attempt to teach, I rarely make attacks, when I do it usually gets flagged and delete by the mods and it is flagrant and obvious.  The rest of the time I am being sarcastic.  I meant that I copy others code all the time and modify. Why do the same work twice?  I see what you did as prudent not a slight against me.

Comment: No no... I asked that only because I though I hurt you. You are very senior and experienced member over here and you have privilege to criticize others if you see something wrong. I will take it positively if you do the same with me. That way I can learn from your experience. Regards.

Comment: Scott, thanks for pointing out the error part.  this explains a break in one of my other codes.  wish i could accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if the vlookup returns an error it will stop the code.  We need to pull that from the code then check for the error:

```
Sub EraseDups()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j as Long
    With ActiveSheet 'Change this to the specific sheet if wanted
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = N To 1 Step -1
             j = 0
             On Error Resume Next
             j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, "A"), Sheet1.Range("A:A"), 0)
             On Error Goto 0
             If j > 0 Then
                 .Rows(i).Delete
             End If
         Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a better practice/solution except looping on a range? Like filtering or using arrays.

Comment: @Masoud Sure, you could use filter, and it would probably be quicker, but that is not what the OP asked.  I tend to keep my code at the same level as what was posted by the OP.

Comment: Yeah. that's a reasonable approach. Thanks

Comment: Currently i use conditional formating to highlight cells that match values in my other sheeti'm making it for someone else.  i rather not have extra steps if possible.

Comment: Scott, it's still doing it :(

Comment: @SantaSecrets still doing what?

Comment: While running Scott's code, remember to activate the Data sheet or use Sheet1.Activate before the With Statement or change the With ActiveSheet with With Sheet1 and change the match function like -- j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, "A"), Sheet2.Range("A:A"), 0)